# Where are my PayPal API credentials (client_id, secret)

Tags: paypal, credentials

Trying to test a simple CURL command to get transaction details (NVP method GetTransactionDetails). Following instructions at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/ I created an application and received test and live App IDs. But nowhere in the email or on the MyApplications page (https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications) does it show me my client_id and secret. Without those I cannot make the API call. Where do I get these credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Realized I was looking at instructions for REST, which requires creating a REST application to get credentials. Getting credentials for a NVP application is completely different (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/).

In case anyone else has this same problem...